# iPhone apps: Can I detect whether a user has a certain app installed from a website?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to use links with special schemes in a website that'll launch an iphone app for a user when clicked (see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095638/iphone-apps-can-i-open-an-app-from-a-link-in-a-website) for reference).

Is there some way that I can detect, in this website, whether my app is installed? (as in, the app that'd handle my special scheme).
My idea is to decide whether to show a "install our app" link, or a "go to our app" link.

Is this possible?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

<del>You can use `-[UIApplication canOpenURL:]` to test whether an app will respond to your custom URL scheme.</del>

<del>Note that this won't detect if an unrelated app hijacks your URL scheme.</del>

Sorry, did not notice the "from a website" part. This only works from an App.

Comment: Look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like-y/1109200#1109200