# Can I launch the native Foursquare iPhone or Android app from a mobile web page?

Tags: foursquare

Does anyone know if it's possible to launch the iPhone or Android Foursquare app from a mobile web page? Is there a custom URL scheme we can use?

Our client would like to give users the option to use the app if they have it installed instead of the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URLs for launching the Foursquare native app can be found here: https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client.html

*As suggested in [that site](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client.html)*, for Android it will fallback to mobile view if the app is not installed, for iPhone you should follow the [UIApplication reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html), specifically `canOpenUrl:` and `openUrl:`

Answer (score 0):

For the android you might want to look at this page:

[Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

For the iphone:

[iPhone apps: Can I open an app from a link in a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095638/iphone-apps-can-i-open-an-app-from-a-link-in-a-website)