# Open app via email

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to send an email with an embedded link that will open an app using [UIApplication openURL:] ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not actually tried this, but I do think that it is possible.  [Here is an article](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) (written back in 2008) that may help.

The idea is that you would create an URI for your app that would launch the app when clicked.  Of course if the user does not have the app open, this will not work.

Again, I have not actually tried this, so good luck.

Also, see this [other article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2095638/330494)

Answer (score -3):

what you are looking for may not possible with iOS.
See - iOS provide a sandbox environment and the only possible way i know is through which any app can be launched is via - application icon click by user or by a Push-Notification received and when user clicks "View" in the dialog.

Comment: If the user has the app installed and the app has registered a custom URL scheme, then the app will be launched when the user tries to open a URL with the corresponding scheme