# Open Twitter app in html

Tags: iphone, html

Is there anyway to open the twitter app from an html link on an iPhone? Kind of how when you click a youtube link it goes to the youtube app.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095638/iphone-apps-can-i-open-an-app-from-a-link-in-a-website).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `twitter://` as the URL and put it in an action for a button or something like so:

```
-(IBAction)openTwitter{
   NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://"];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];   
}
```

If you meant html on a website you'd use `<a href="twitter://">tap me to go to twitter</a>` for the link.

[URL Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) are shown [here](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) and you can grab some more handy information about them too.

I'd probably recommend @Arab_Geek's solution though as it isn't that much of a trouble and it's giving back control to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Twitter integratation for iOS 5 ([TWTweetComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL * twitterURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://"];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:twitterURL])
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:twitterURL];
```

Comment: I'm talking about html, not objective-c