# How to open up a app on your phone via link on site

Tags: javascript, android, html, iphone, apache-cordova

Is there a way to open a app on your phone, if you click a link on your site?

for example your on your phone browsing the site and it says for more info open "ExampleApp" if the app is installed it will open up the app on there phone.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095638/iphone-apps-can-i-open-an-app-from-a-link-in-a-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown on this link : [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

It is possible if your main activity has the BROWSABLE intent filter.

The href attribute will get the package name as a value